# Fixed navigation internal links

Tags: html, css, navigation, hyperlink

I have a fixed nav at the top of my site, which links to sections lower down on the page. However, since the nav is fixed at the top of the page and not part of the document flow, it overlaps part of the section I link to, rather than the bottom of the nav touching the exact top of the section. Here's and example of what I mean: http://nashwp.guuhuu.com/

But what I want is the bottom of the nav to stop right at the beginning of the section so it does not overlap. Here is an example: http://wpdemo.themi.co/rythm/

So how do I achieve this? Is Javascript the only way or can I do it with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the only way is with Javascript.  Since it's probably using anchor tags (or at least that's a good way to do it).

When I do stuff like this I have to see how far down the page I'm going to animate and then add X amount of pixels to offset the fixed navbar.  Otherwise the area I want to go to goes behind the fixed nav (which isn't really great).

So yes the best way is probably JS.   You could also look into applying a margin or padding to the element that is being scrolled to.  But I'm not sure if the browser always scrolls to the very top of that element (regardless of margin or padding).

Comment: I am actually using the waypoints javascript thingy (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) for my nav. Is there a way to incorporate this offset into it? I know nothing about Jquery.